# How do I print String value in my Array List without printing the null value?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, null

```
cars =new ArrayList<Car>();
cars.add(new Car(2016,"honda","civic"));
cars.add(new Car(2017,"Lamborghini","aventador")); 
cars.add(new Car(2000,null,"caravan"));
cars.add(new Car(2010,"dodge",null));
```

How do I print and skip the null value like this:

```
hondacivicLamborghiniaventadorcaravandodge
```

Comment: A `for` loop, a null check and a print statement?

Comment: `cards.stream().flatMap(car -> Stream.of(car.getMake(), car.getModel())).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEachOrdered(System.out::print);`

Comment: @shmosel Nice comment, thanks for teaching me.

Comment: @shmosel  I don't understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't add** `null`, **just replace it with** `""` :

Example :

```
cars.add(new Car(2000,"","caravan"));
cars.add(new Car(2010,"dodge",""));
```

Code :

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

cars.add(new Car(2016,"honda","civic"));
cars.add(new Car(2017,"Lamborghini","aventador")); 
cars.add(new Car(2000,"","caravan"));
cars.add(new Car(2010,"dodge",""));

for(Car c : cars) {
 System.out.print(c.getCompanyName() + "" + c.getCarName());
}
```

Alternatively update the code to this for skipping the `null` values:

```
for(Car c : cars) {
   String data = ((c.getCompanyName() != null) ? c.getCompanyName(): "") + ((c.getCarName() != null) ? c.getCarName() : ""); 
   System.out.print(data);
}
```

Comment: I cannot change anything in the table. I need to find a way to skip the null value and print like this: hondacivicLamborghiniaventadorcaravandodge

Comment: @StevenChen I have updated the solution for skipping the null values.